# Remote connection

Tags: powershell, csv

```
$hostList = cat C:\hostfile.csv

foreach($_ in $hostList){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
    ...
    }
```

The content of hostfile.csv is (test purposes):

```
localhost,127.0.0.1
```

This .csv file is a single line, without headers. 
The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Invoke-Command : One or more computer names is not valid. If you are trying to pass a UR
I, use the -ConnectionUri parameter or pass URI objects instead of strings.
```

Am I defining the `foreach` wrong or is it not possible to fill in the value of the .csv in `$_`?

EDIT: In the end I want to extend the .csv with real-world IP adresses and hostnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after invoking `$hostList = cat C:\hostfile.csv` you have a string not an array.

You need to split a string by comma. SO the code could be following:

```
$hostList = cat C:\hostfile.csv

foreach($_ in $hostList){
    $line = $_.Split(',');
    $host = $line[0];
    $ip = $line[1];
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $host -ScriptBlock {
    ...
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Because all values are in one line the above coe must be changed to below:

```
$hostList = (cat C:\hostfile.csv).Split(',');

foreach($_ in $hostList){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that all the values are on a single line. I want to connect on either IP or hostname. Thank you for the input tho!

Comment: @SiemHermans look at update, and you do not need to thanks, just vote up answer or when it is goog for you mark it as answer (you could do both)

Comment: Alright, so by splitting it on the ',' you create seperate values. Adding those seperate values makes $hostList an array as to where simply importing the .csv would not. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe winrm is not configured to allow connection by IP address could you try to resolve the adress to hostname before using invoke-command ?

btw you have to split your line to get the hosts :

```
$hostList | |% { 
    $_ -split ',' | % {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_).hostname -ScriptBlock {
            ...
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: When I fill in the IP adress or the hostname it works. Stuff goes crazy when I try to do it for more values in a row.